# HandConstraintPalmUp issue after location lost(Trying to map your surroundings)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

[Hololens 2 location lost screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aiw6F.png) [MRTK HandConstraintPalmUp values 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcZID.png) [MRTK HandConstraintPalmUp values 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGFzQ.png) [Tryout HandConstraintPalmUp values 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrdaR.png) [Tryout HandConstraintPalmUp values 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waWsH.png)

Issue faced : Palm up not getting triggered after location lost due to change in config values.

I took the MRTK HandCoach example scene and altered the config values as given in the attached screenshots.
MRTK Screenshots are followed by the tryout screenshots.

After changing these values, the palm up isnt getting triggered in my tryout. The change in config values was to accommodate a need to trigger palmup only when a flat hand is perpendicular and facing the camera.

On a deep-dive, found that the Use Gaze Activation change is causing this issue. Trying to understand the reason behind why this change is impacting the feature.

@hololens
@windows-mixed-reality

Comment: There is a similar issue post in the GitHub portal:[Loss of Spatial Mapping Causes Phantom Hand Tracking](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/7896), as the last comment says, it fixed by [#9890](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/9890). Could you upgrade to the latest MRTK and try again?

Comment: Also,  we currently recommend installing Unity 2020.3 LTS with the latest Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin for Mixed Reality development, for more information please see:[Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version)

Comment: BTW, MRTK 2.7.3 is now available for download, please refer to this link: [Microsoft Mixed Reality Toolkit v2.7.3](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases/tag/2.7.3)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Will try and let you know.